# Is it possible to block a data set programmatically through the API in Carto?

Tags: carto, api, lock

We are automating the creation of data sets with Carto. Now we would like to be able to lock to avoid unwanted changes in the data.

We know that this can be done through the dashboard, but is it possible to do it through the API? We do not find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API to perform that task, even it's supported (with proper warning notice) by [CARTO Python SDK](https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-python#import-api), search for the `Update the properties of a dataset` example. In your case you are looking for the `dataset.locked` property.